# Display name/label/description in Highchart timeline tooltips

Tags: highcharts, timeline

I've created a composite chart which combines a line chart with two overlapping event series.

I would like each event to appear exactly as shown, but with a tooltip showing start and end times of the event, and a short description with with a link.

By default (no name/label/description defined for the data point), the tooltip shows the start/end times, nicely formatted (and for some reason with the label '{series name}: false').

However if I define a name/label/description (as for the first event in series 2 in [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t7x3L6wm/2/) ):

- None of these values appear in the tooltip
- The start/end times now appear as unformatted numbers

```js
        {
            "name": "My Name",
            "label": "My Label",
            "description": "My Description",
            x: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 21, 3),
            x2: Date.UTC(2014, 10, 21, 5),
            y: 1
        }
```

How can I decide the content and format of the tooltip? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `series.tooltip.pointFormatter` callback to customize your tooltip.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/twjasmqo/

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.pointFormatter